# Linq to Entities error when using a view model in a select list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm attempting to create a `SelectList` by wrapping a whole bunch of model entities in individual view model entities.

I have a view model class:

```
public class ReferenceDocumentSelectionViewModel
{
    public ReferenceDocument Document { get; set; }

    public int ID { get { return Document.ID; } }

    public String DisplayText 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return Document.DocumentNumber + 
                   Document.Version + 
                   Document.Revision + 
                   Document.Sheet; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Then I'm attempting to use lambda expressesions to create a list of these objects:

```
var docs =  _db.ReferenceDocuments
               .Select(r => new ReferenceDocumentSelectionViewModel() 
               { 
                   Document = r 
               });
```

before assigning them to a `SelectList`:

```
ReferenceDocList = new SelectList(docs.OrderBy(r => r.DisplayText), 
                                  "ID", 
                                  "DisplayText");
```

In my view I access the SelectList like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedReferenceDoc, 
                      Model.ReferenceDocList, 
                      "-Select-", 
                      new { id = "ReferenceList" })
```

where `model.SelectedReferenceDoc` is an integer property on another view model.

I thought this would work but instead I'm getting the following error:

> The specified type member 'DisplayText' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

Help?

**EDIT:** On further investigation, it seems it's the `docs.OrderBy(r => r.DisplayText)` that is causing the issue.  If I remove that, it works fine.  Any ideas of why that is not allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `DisplayText` is not a mapped property EF does not know how to translate this to SQL. Thats why it gives you an error.

You can either use LINQ-to-Objects Sorting here by first loading all elements

```
var docs =  _db.ReferenceDocuments
               .Select(r => new ReferenceDocumentSelectionViewModel() 
               { 
                   Document = r 
               }).ToList();
```

Then sort them in memory

```
ReferenceDocList = new SelectList(docs.OrderBy(r => r.DisplayText), 
                                  "ID", 
                                  "DisplayText");
```

Or sort by each property

```
var docs =  _db.ReferenceDocuments
               .OrderBy(r => r.DocumentNumber)
               .ThenBy(r => r.Version)
               .ThenBy(r => r.Revision)
               .ThenBy(r => r.Sheet)
               .Select(r => new ReferenceDocumentSelectionViewModel() 
               { 
                   Document = r 
               });

ReferenceDocList = new SelectList(docs, 
                                  "ID", 
                                  "DisplayText");
```

This way sorting will be done in the database it is much more efficient than doing the sorting in memory.

Hence the second option is preferred.

Comment: Another alternative is .AsEnumerable()

Comment: Great, thanks for the solution! Could you please explain WHY this is the way to do it?  Which would be more efficient, the first option or the second option?

Comment: The reason it's necessary is because the data passed into `DropDownListFor` is still an `IQueryable`.  Any ordering done in that context will have an attempt be converted to SQL.  Therefore, ordering by `DisplayText` won't work since that value is derived only through C# code.  Ordering by only database columns is one workaround, or converting to a plain `IEnumerable` through `AsEnumerable` is another (the latter lets the CLR sort the data instead of the database).

Comment: Fantastic Eranga, exactly the answer I was looking for. And thanks for your comment @Jacob.